# Chaining VisualStates In Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, expression-blend

I have three VisualStates that each have animation in them and I would like to chain them together. I want one state to begin after the last one has completed. How do I do this in Silverlight without a lot of smelly code?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting the animations in a single storyboard? Visual states were not designed to do what you are trying to do (start one animation after another has finished) but storyboards were.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use event "Completed" to detect when animation is over and start another animation.

Comment: How about a behavior to turn that into a trigger

Comment: @JayKannan I'm not working with Silverlight anymore, sorry. I moved to GWT.